# 3D CNN Model only outputs positive values

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, encoder-decoder

I am using 3D Encoder-Decoder model. My input to the model is a 3D grid with added noise. The values contained in the grid are both positive and negative. I want to denoise the model. I don’t know why but my model outputs only positive value. I am using the L1 loss function. My training as well as validation loss is also decreasing with the epochs. But when I test the model, it only outputs the positive values. However, It should just denoise the input and outputs both positive and negative numbers. I am using PyTorch automatic mixed precision for the training. Can someone help me on this. I have already spend too much time on this. But I can not fix it. If training scrip is needed I can also provide that.

The pytorch model is given below:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class Model_ED(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, bn=True):
        super(Model_ED, self).__init__()

        #### ENCODER ####
        self.en_1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(1, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            #nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv3d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )

        self.en_2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(32, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv3d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )

        self.en_3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv3d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv3d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )

        #### DECODER ####
        self.de_3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(128, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv3d(32, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )

        self.de_2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(64, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv3d(16, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            # nn.Tanh(),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )

        self.de_1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(16, 1, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        )

        self.mp = nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.upsample = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)

    def forward(self, input_tsdf_vol):

        # feature encoding
        en_1 = self.en_1(input_tsdf_vol)
        en_2 = self.mp(self.en_2(en_1))
        en_3 = self.mp(self.en_3(en_2))

        # feature decoding
        up_3 = self.upsample(en_3)
        f_cat_3 = torch.cat([up_3, en_2], dim=1)
        de_3 = self.de_3(f_cat_3)

        up_2 = self.upsample(de_3)
        f_cat_2 = torch.cat([up_2, en_1], dim=1)
        de_2 = self.de_2(f_cat_2)

        de_1 = self.de_1(de_2)

        return de_1
```

Comment: ReLU's output range is 0 to inf.

Comment: What is your problem... and your question?

Comment: @KDecker I am not using ReLU at the last layer.

Comment: @Ivan. Since my input to model is noisy 3d grid with positive and negative values. but my model outputs only positive values. It should outpus negative values where input is negative.

Comment: What are you trying to estimate?

Comment: @Rajat Yes but you use them throughout and one of your very last layers is a `MaxPool`. So unless that `de_1` layer can produce "many" negative values, so much so that the `MaxPool` can only pool over negatives, it will be very difficult for the network to output negative values. // At the least you may want to try an average pooling with an activation function that can produce `[-1, 1]` and normalize the input values accordingly.

Comment: @KDecker, I don't use maxpool over de_1 layer output.